# Get last day of month - Different output than expected

Tags: javascript

I have searched and seen answers to this question here on Stack Overflow. But for some weird reason or maybe an upgrade to whatever could have been upgraded. When I use in JavaScript: `Date(2018,2,0)`, this will retrieve the last day of February. But with all the answers I checked, to get the last day of February, I should have written: `Date(2018,3,0)`.

My question is basically this. Did I miss something to get different outputs for a function that was used years ago with the retrieve last day of month day 0 trick? My server's date is okay and timezone is perfectly fine. So why would I have a different output than all answers I've seen so far for the same question?

OK, here is my code for those that want it:

```
// Load calendar days in a TR element
function ShowCalDays(TableId,cyear,cmonth,clickable = "") {
  var curm = parseInt(cmonth,10);
  var cury = parseInt(cyear,10);
  var curd = 0;
  var curw = 0;
  var ictr = 0;
  var trdata = "";
  var newweek = "";
  var cal_tab = document.getElementById(TableId);
  var cal_tr = 0;
  var cal_td = 0;
  var cal_txt = 0;
  var cal_weeks = document.getElementById("week");

  // Delete all week days to refresh calendar
  while (cal_weeks) {
    cal_weeks.parentNode.removeChild(cal_weeks);
    cal_weeks = document.getElementById("week");
  }

  // Last day
  var ldt = new Date(cury,curm,0);
  // First day
  var fdt = new Date(parseInt(cyear,10),parseInt(cmonth,10),1);
  // Retrieve last day of month
  curd = ldt.getDate();
  // Get week day number
  curw = fdt.getDay();

  cury = 0;
  cal_tr = document.createElement("tr");
  cal_tab.appendChild(cal_tr);
  // Loop all days of the month and build days table
  for (ictr=0 - curw;ictr<=curd;ictr++) {
    newweek = "";
    cury++;
    cal_td = document.createElement("td");
    if (clickable == "y" && ictr > 0) {cal_td.style.cursor = "pointer";}
    // Set new week row
    if (cury > 7)   {cal_tr = document.createElement("tr");}
    // Set TD value
    if (ictr > 0) {newweek = ictr.toString();}
    // Create td and tr element AND insert text inside
    cal_txt = document.createTextNode(newweek);
    cal_td.appendChild(cal_txt);
    cal_tr.appendChild(cal_td);
    cal_tr.id = "week";
    if (cury > 7){
        cal_tab.appendChild(cal_tr);
        cury = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your title is a little confusing and doesn't match well with the question text. Are you saying the Firefox 58.0.2 is giving you a different date than other browsers? Can you please show the exact code you're using to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

[Per the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **Note:** The argument `month` is 0-based. This means that `January = 0` and `December = 11`.

So `new Date(2018, 2, 0)` creates a date—the 0th day of March, or the last day of February. Firefox isn't 'wrong' in this case, and other browsers shouldn't act any differently since this is standardized behavior.

Comment: Does this explain why the results are different in Firefox? That's what the title seems to say...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Hmm, I was thinking about that too. It makes 0 sense that Firefox of all browsers would behave like this on something as fundamental as the `Date` constructor... I can't check but it doesn't make sense that other browsers are "wrong".

Comment: I changed the month by adding 1 to it, but then again, still not the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the situation. After considering the 0 base answer. I took another look at my code and changed a few things to retry the whole thing to work as it's intended to. And as always, my bad, I missed a small information. Thanks A LOT for your support people, as always.

So here is the final code corrected and functionnal.

```
// Load calendar days in a TR element
function ShowCalDays(TableId,cyear,cmonth,clickable = "") {
  var curm = parseInt(cmonth,10);
  var cury = parseInt(cyear,10);
  var curd = 0;
  var curw = 0;
  var ictr = 0;
  var trdata = "";
  var newweek = "";
  var cal_tab = document.getElementById(TableId);
  var cal_tr = 0;
  var cal_td = 0;
  var cal_txt = 0;
  var cal_weeks = document.getElementById("week");

  // Delete all week days to refresh calendar
  while (cal_weeks) {
    cal_weeks.parentNode.removeChild(cal_weeks);
    cal_weeks = document.getElementById("week");
  }

  // If month is december, set next month as January of next year
  // to retrieve last day of december
  if (curm == 12) {
    curm = 0;
    cury += 1;
  }

  // Last day
  var ldt = new Date(cury,curm,0);
  // First day
  var fdt = new Date(parseInt(cyear,10),parseInt(cmonth,10)-1,1);
  // Retrieve last day of month
  curd = ldt.getDate();
  // Get week day number
  curw = fdt.getDay();

  cury = 0;
  cal_tr = document.createElement("tr");
  cal_tab.appendChild(cal_tr);
  // Loop all days of the month and build days table
  for (ictr=1 - curw;ictr<=curd;ictr++) {
    newweek = "";
    cury++;
    cal_td = document.createElement("td");
    if (clickable == "y" && ictr > 0) {cal_td.style.cursor = "pointer";}
    // Set new week row
    if (cury > 7)   {cal_tr = document.createElement("tr");}
    // Set TD value
    if (ictr > 0) {newweek = ictr.toString();}
      // Create td and tr element AND insert text inside
      cal_txt = document.createTextNode(newweek);
      cal_td.appendChild(cal_txt);
      cal_tr.appendChild(cal_td);
      cal_tr.id = "week";
      if (cury > 7){
        cal_tab.appendChild(cal_tr);
        cury = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> My server's date is ok and timezone is perfectly fine

Since javascript is a client side scripting language, unless you're using something like NodeJS to run javascript code on the server, the date and timezone on the server aren't relevant. What is relevant is the date and timezone on your client.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to point it out. Maybe it would be better I wrote it as a comment? I wrote it as an answer because there are no quotes on comments and it was easier for me to write it like this

Comment: @user3362334 Yeah, a comment would have more suited. I usually signify a quote in a comment with some italics and double quotes: *"foobar, or not to foobar"*